# SAP OData Service - X-CSRF-Token validation failed from client app

Tags: c#, odata, csrf, kerberos, sap-gateway

Anyone here have good knowledge of X-CSRF-Token behaviour on SAP OData services, in particular when used with Windows Auth (Kerberos) authentication?

Am developing against GET/PUT services which behave fine in testing via Postman; X-CSRF-Token retrieval happens just before a PUT call, and the PUT call is accepted when the token is submitted back (along with cookies from the SAP Portal session).

Test service is on HTTPS on URL such as:
https://sapqe0.clientname.com.au:44380/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_SERVICE_NAME_SRV/TestService('parameter')

When trying from a .NET client app, GET calls work fine including token retrieval, but the PUT returns a 403 'CSRF Token Validation Failed' error, despite seemingly valid token passed.

Have traced through with Fiddler, and the request/response packets look identical to those sent by Postman. Only difference I see is the client app receives a different token on every request, while Postman receives the same token on successive calls. May imply that session isn't recognized properly from the app?

The C# app is using the Windows identity (DefaultCredentials) and first hits the SAP Portal to get cookies and attach to OData requests.

Any clues on what would cause a CSRF token validation failure in this scenario?

Comment: have you solved your problem? i got the same

Comment: Unfortunately not! Many days of testing later, we opted to modify the SAP service with a flag to disable CSRF validation (so just Windows identity would be validated). That works fine, but still not sure what we did wrong on token retrieval/submission...

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer, we did the same here

Answer (score 2):

here is a working solution without disabling the token.
You have to share not only the token, but also the cookiecontainer between your requests.

```
private readonly CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
private string csrfToken;

private void GetToken(Uri url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Credentials = Credentials;
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    request.Headers["x-csrf-token"] = "Fetch";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    csrfToken = response.Headers.Get("x-csrf-token");
}
```